# gitignore cannot exclude folders from exclusion

Tags: git, gitignore

I have troubles excluding a pattern from .gitignore (I want the folder to be added)

currently my .gitignore is like:

```
/*
!file1.conf
!file2.ini
!*.xml
!confs/*
```

in a hierarchy that have really many files

When I `git add .` it correctly add `xml`s present in the root directory along with `file1.conf` and `file2.ini` but no file from `confs/` folder is added.

`git status` returns:

```
file1.conf  
file2.ini
data1.xml
logback.xml
```

but the expected `confs/filea.json` is missing

Answer (score 2):

You should include folder *and* folder contents, so you need both `confs/` and `confs/*`:

```
*
!file1.conf
!file2.ini
!*.xml
!confs/
!confs/*
```

[image: SourceTree view]
[image: Directory structure]